# How to design a plugin in Outlook that automatically inserts a signature in the mails users compose?

Tags: plugins, outlook-addin

To make calls to the API, I have to compose and parse XML that's UTF-8 valid, post it over https, verify the https endpoint certificate and ensure XML requests are signed with HMAC-SHA1.

Comment: In Outlook, tick "Attach Signature Automatically" option... /sarcasm>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signature is a part of the message body. There are three main ways for working with bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. Word editor. The Inspector class provides the [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body. Outlook uses Word as an email editor.

You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .

To get started developing an add-in, see [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).